# JBoss application deployment error persists even after using a fresh JBoss distribution on Ubuntu

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, cxf, ubuntu-10.04

I am facing a very weird problem. This is one of those errors that just doesn't make sense. Please read till the end before jumping to conclusions.

1. When I deploy our web application (.ear file) containing web services written in Apache CXF on JBoss without making any changes to the web.xml file, everything seems to work fine.
2. When I make some changes to the web.xml file and rebuild the ear and redeploy the application, JBoss is unable to deploy my application because of some class loader conflicts. This is completely alright because I am expecting JBoss to throw these errors.
3. After I stop the JBoss server instance and revert the changes made in Step 2 to the web.xml and rebuild my .ear file and redeploy the application in JBoss, the same errors that were thrown in Step 2 are thrown again. How is this possible considering that I reverted all the changes I had made to the web.xml in Step 2 and restarted JBoss with a fresh .ear file to use?
4. I even tried downloading a fresh copy of JBoss and rebuilding and redeploying the application on the fresh copy. The same errors that were displayed in Step 2 are displayed in the application even though the web.xml no longer contains the changes that were made in step 2.

The only way I am able to get rid of the errors is by taking a fresh checkout of my code base and building my application and deploying a fresh version of my application in a fresh JBoss server. This doesn't make sense because changing the web.xml doesn't implicitly change other files or classes in the application as far as my knowledge goes.

I am clueless about how to solve this problem. The only change I make is to the web.xml file and I don't touch any other classes or files. Why do the errors persist permanently?

Comment: what was the error? could you add those errors here?

Comment: I have intentionally not provided the errors because I am not concerned with the error. I am concerned with the strange behavior where these errors persist across a new build or a new JBoss distribution. There has got to be some temporary files that are being used by Ubuntu or the application itself that persist beyond JBoss or my application.

Answer (score 0):

This time before you start your JBoss server, delete tmp and work folders under the server profile directory.  That should take care of it.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Still facing the same problem. I deployed me application in a fresh copy of JBoss. Still getting the same issue.

Comment: It would be tough to guess what else could it be in absence of error stacktrace